# Disable white-space mode emacs-26.3

Tags: init-file, whitespace-mode

I tried to highlight lines that exceed 80 columns using `whitespace-mode`. Eventually didn't like that idea and removed that from my `init.el`. However, the whitespaces are shown as `.` and line ends are `$` in the files that I edit. How can I get rid of that. I tried adding the following to the `init.el` file. But that doesn't work between restarted session. 
`(whitespace-mode 0)`. Every time I source the `init.el` by `load-file` it works but not otherwise. I am a newbie `emacs` user and getting my way around with emacs and lisp. Could any one suggest me how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Did you try searching for `whitespace` in your init file? You may still have a setting in there that causes problems. Also, check the value of the variable `whitespace-global-modes`? If non-nil, try to find where it is set and change it to nil.

Comment: What @NickD said (but it's `global-whitespace-mode`).

Comment: I have looked every line of my `init.el` file but `whitespace-mode` was nowhere. However, upon rebooting my system, I start to see my regular files without `whitespace-mode` characters. Could someone care to advice/explain how/why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whitespace-mode` is local to a buffer.

If you put `(whitespace-mode 0)` in your init file it affects only the buffer than happens to be current at the time that sexp is evaluated.  Don't do that.

Instead, bisect your init file to find out just which part of it is enabling whitespace mode wherever you see it but don't want it.  And look for `global-whitespace-mode`, which turns it on everywhere.